# Transience/Recurrence Proof

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let ${x_n}$ be a discrete time Markov Chain with transition probability matrix $P$ and $p_{ii}$<1 for all $i \in S$ . Let ${y_n}$ be a MC with transition matrix $P'$ such that $p'_{i,i}=0$ and $p'_{i,j}=p_{i,j}/(1-p_{i,i})$. Show that $x_n$ is recurrent iff $y_n$ is recurrent.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could guide me with this proof. My approach was to show $p^{(n)}_{i,j} \leq p^{'(n)}_{i,j}$ for $i \neq j$ so i could sum over both sides but didn't have much luck.

Comment: $\{Y_n\}$ is just $\{X_n\}$ without self-transitions, which do not affect recurrence unless there is an absorbing state (which we are assuming there is not).

Comment: Indeed the random sets $\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ and $\{y_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ can be made to coincide, defining recursively $y_n=x_{t(n)}$ with $t(0)=0$ and, for every $n\geqslant0$, $t(n+1)=\inf\{k\geqslant t(n)\mid x_k\ne x_{t(n)}\}$. The result follows.